# routing or dynamic creation of LWC Open Source components to avoid multiple IF conditions

Tags: lwc-oss

we are working on LWC Open Source and to navigate to the new component, currently we are using if:true with a boolean value which is not appropriate for a long run. Is there any other way to achieve this either by the help of routing or dynamic creation of components in LWC Open Source?

Answer (score 1):

Here’s how you can create components dynamically. It’s just the standard way how you’d instantiate an LWC.

Note that you have to clean up things afterwards.

https://github.com/pmdartus/rcast/blob/master/src/client/modules/rcast/app/app.js#L91

The example also shows how to use that with a custom routing package.

https://github.com/pmdartus/rcast/blob/master/src/client/modules/rcast/app/app.js#L30

Comment: I get a 404 when trying to access the github links in your answer. Please update them if you know the correct repository location or add code snippets if not.